# Meteor/Javascript - Is this bad practice? - Declaring var

Tags: javascript, meteor

In javascript/Meteor, if I have multiple methods that use the same class, is it a bad practice or good practice to declare it outside the method and reuse the class?

Which of the two options is actually the proper way to code?

i.e. Option 1

```
Meteor.methods({
  do1: function () {
    var facebook = facebook('facebook id');
    facebook.something1()
  },
  do2: function () {
    var facebook = facebook('facebook id');
    facebook.something2()
  }
})
```

i.e. Option 2

```
facebook = facebook('facebook id');

Meteor.methods({
  do1: function () {
    facebook.something1()
  },
  do2: function () {
    facebook.something2()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's a good practise to put it outside (so that you don't repeat yourself), but it's a bad practise not to actually declare it.

```
var facebook = facebook('facebook id'); /*
^^^ use var! */    
Meteor.methods({
  do1: function () {
    facebook.something1()
  },
  do2: function () {
    facebook.something2()
  }
});
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. How silly of me. I'll mark as answer when the time allows me to.